# what is the best way to read and parse millions of files on WindowsNT

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

i have millions of files in one directory(on directory with many child directorys),
these files are all small files.

i think there are 2 challenges:

1. how to traverse the directory to find all files. i have try the 'FindFirstFile/FindNextFile' way, but i feel it is too slow.Should I use the *Windows Change Journal*?
2. after i have find all filenames, i need read a whole file to memory,and then parse it.Should I use the FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN flag? or is there more efficient way?

Comment: i think i can get some **Efficiency Improving** from read a whole file into the memory. perhaps i was wrong. i need write a programe to prove it.

Comment: How slow is slow exactly? How long does `FindFirstFile` take?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to kick around..

- Text Crawler - Awesome indispensable Windows Search Tool - http://digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawler.html
- Microsoft log parser - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx
- If you have a SQL (or MySQL) Server that has enough space, you can setup a SQL Job to import/link to the files in question, then you can query them

What my fear is that if you load the content of the file/s into memory, you are going to run out of server memory quickly.  What you need to do is locate the files in question and write the results to a log or report that you can parse out and interpret.

Comment: i setup the Text Crawler, i use the apimon to see the api call.i found it use the FindFirstFile/FindNextFile.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS, or in fact any non-specialized file system will be slow with millions of small files. That's the territory of databases.

If the files are in fact small, it doesn't matter at all how you read them. Overhead costs will dominate. It may be worthwhile to use a second thread, but a third thread is unlikely to help further.

Also, use `FindFirstFileEx` to speed up the search. You don't need alternate file names but would prefer a larger buffer.

Comment: As much as I love Windows, I think Linux with ext3 or ext4 handles large numbers of files much better/faster than NTFS.

Comment: I've actually written an ext3 boot loader (easy, same as ext2) and I'd disagree. You really want a structured storage of filenames, the list in ext3 isn't efficient.

Comment: I'm not saying it's efficient compared to a database (or something more suited to the task) obviously, but are you saying it's not faster than NTFS? I'm pretty sure it is...

Comment: @Mehrdad: Depends on the exact task at hand, but e.g. picking one file by name from a directory with 1000 files is O(log N) on NTFS and O(N) on ext3.

Comment: Uh, I meant for the operation that the OP was concerned with, *"traverse the directory to find all files"*, not some random task. Can you really claim NTFS is faster at that job? Because I'm pretty sure it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567047.aspx) with a large buffer (say, 64 KB) to query for the children.
   This function is the absolute limit to the fastest you can possibly communicate with the file system.

If that doesn't work for you, you can read the NTFS file table directly, but that means you'll have to have administrative privileges and will need to implement the file system reader by hand.